# how to make exported variable be optional in svelte.js framework?

Tags: javascript, svelte

let's say I want to have a custom attribute where I can get some information from the parent element.

in svelte is easy, the syntax is like this:

**MyChild.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let x;
</script>

<div>choosed value: {x}</div>
```

**MyParent.svelte**

```html
<main>
 <MyChild x={10} />
</main>
```

but let's say I didn't want to always pass the attribute value

```html
<MyChild x={10} />
<MyChild /> <!-- this time I don't want to pass the value -->
```

I want if I don't pass the value then it will use a secondary value.

in react we have [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) or `||`,

- but in svelte don't seem to work
- seems mandatory

  > Property 'x' is missing in type...

so svelte tell me the problem before compiling

- which is safe and good
- but in my case,

  - I want to create 1 attribute that is mandatory,
  - and other 5 optional (not important, in most case are repetitive so this is why are optional)

is there a workaround?

---

so I want something like

```
export let x ?? 0;
// get "x" if you find an attribute
// then set the variable "x" to "x"

// but if the user doesn't add the attribute uses the second value "??"
// same as if x is undefined/null
```

or like this

```
export let x ?? 4.1658126;
```

or like this

```
export let x ?? MY_CONSTANT_VAR;
```

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/ed0fe4b6d2634eada2627a06a72fa9a6?version=3.12.1

Comment: `export let x = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this:

```html
<script>
  export let x = 0;
</script>

<div>choosed value: {x}</div>
```

now it will work in the parent without that error in the IDE

```html
<main>
 <MyChild x={10} /> <!-- choosed value: 10 -->
 <MyChild />        <!-- choosed value: 0  -->
</main>
```

There is no need for `??`, just use `=`

Comment: every time svelte.js surprise me :) it is very beautiful to work with it! thanks. it is super simple. thanks for the answer